# How to get first Activation date of page?

Tags: aem, aem-6

I have activated page 10 times in a year . I want date on which i did first time activation.

How can i get this? Can i do this through version history? 
If yes then How/when new version of node created ?

Comment: Do you want to do this programmatically or as editor in the UI?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. Check in page sidekick Audit log
2. You can check  in Archive tab in workflow.When  we  activate the page it call page publish workflow on page activate

http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/workflow/content/console.html

Comment: The audit log is purged from time to time. I think the default is every three months. So if the page was activated for the first time years ago it won't show up in the audit log.